# Do I need (in) connections (eg: port 18080 open) in order to participate in Dandelion++?

Tags: full-node, dandelion++

Do I need to have (in) connections for Dandelion++ to work? For example, having port 18080 open.

I currently only have 12(out)+1(in) connections, with an open 18080 port. Will I get more (in) connections?

I am only asking because someone told me that 18080 does not need to be opened in order for the node to participate in Dandelion so I just want to make sure?

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to forward or open any ports for Dandelion++ to work.